# how tp properly process java variable that if conditions

Tags: java

if I have a variable that can be multiple value depends on some conditions, how do I properly write the definition?

For example:

```
// First part
if (condition a) {
    int a = 1
} else {
    int a = 2
}

// Second part
if (a == 1) {process 1}
if (a == 2) {process 2}
```

But If I write it this way, the second part will give error message that it does not recognize what is `a`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give `a` greater visibility (or just move your `process 1` and `process 2` into the first `if` block and eliminate `a`). Assuming you want option 1:

```
int a;
if (condition a) {
    a = 1;
} else {
    a = 2;
}
```

That could also be written as a ternary

```
int a = (condition a) ? 1 : 2;
```

And for your second part, don't forget that `==` is how you test equality (not `=`, that is assignment)

```
if (a == 1) { 
    process 1
} else if (a == 2) {
    process 2
}
```

Comment: Right, that was a typo, I mean to say `==`